# How can I stop music from looping for every cut of video in VirtualDub?

Tags: virtualdub

I'm trying to use VirtualDub to make a video. I have a 3 second clip that I copy and pasted multiple times to loop it. When I try to add music, the music loops when a new loop of the video starts.

I've tried a lot of things to make the music not loop, so I ask, how can I not get the music to copy paste with the video? (Keep in mind I do the copy pasting before I add the music.

Answer (score 0):

Append the videos together, write them out.
Take the final looped video, load it back into V-dub select to Direct stream the video, direct stream will not re-encode the video , so it will not be degraded again.
Add your Audio stream to that final video, have the audio stream be long enough in time to play for the whole video.